# Cannot install an already COMPILED & SIGNED Apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk, apksigner

### **About the problem**

• APK is decompiled and recompiled using [APK Easy Tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-apk-easy-tool-v1-02-windows-gui-t3333960), it's basically a GUI version of [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) plus some good stuff like sign or zipalign options. 

• This tool gives you 2 options, either Google's (apksigner) or [bootstraponline (signapk)](https://github.com/appium/sign), if you sign your APK using this latter, the app will work fine on devices but you can't upload it to playstore because of this error : [**(click to view the image)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e67Dz.png)

 
• Now when you try to sign the APK using Google's (apksigner), the app doesn't install on devices from the first place :
                                 - Genymotion [**(click to view the image)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbufW.png)
                                 - Android Studio emulator [**(click to view the image)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFGoq.png)

### **What I have tried already**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40064149/9732803 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636921/9732803

### *EDIT

[@Arnold Parge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008962/arnold-parge)
[#comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146401/cannot-install-an-already-compiled-signed-apk-file#comment87311300_50146401) is right! 
And to be honest i don't know what's the reason behind this, now my new question is considering that my APK `minSkdVersion is 16` & the `targetSdkVersion is 27`, if i upload the APK to the playstore, will my app support most of API levels from 16 to 27+ ?

***EMULATORS***  (Genymotion, BlueStacks, Android Studio Emulator)
• Samsung Galaxy S3    - API 16 (4.4.1) => **WORKING!** 
• BlueStacks 3                - API 19 (4.4.2) => Not Working! 
• Google Nexus 7           - API 21 (5.0.0) => Not Working! 
• Google Nexus 5           - API 24 (7.0) => Not Working! 
***REAL DEVICE*** 
• Samsung Galaxy J1    - API 19 (4.4.4) => **WORKING!**

Comment: Why can't you upload it?  What error was given?  It doesn't just refuse for no reason.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for you reply, so when i sign the APK with my own keystore using apksigner and i align it with zipalign, the APK cannot be installed on the emulator, so why would i upload it to the store if it's not working in the first place?

Comment: Your apk is not being properly built using the apktools you are using. I have seen these errors on a couple of times occurring for the applications compiled using apktool or its other variants. I am actually not sure why are you reverse-engineering your own application and then recompiling it.

Comment: @Matiah on some emulator release build does not work. Don't worry, go ahead and upload on playstore. Btw you can test it on real device though..

Comment: Because your questions title says you can't do it. That means you tried. If you haven't, fix your question.  Also, when you install it gives you an error reason. What was it? And add another user said, signing is the last step. Do not align or otherwise change the file after signing

Comment: Why do you write about upload in your title while you can't even compile your app?

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the new V2 signature, apksigner uses both V1 & V2 by default, i want to try to sign my APK using V1 signature only, how can i do that ? using apksigner not jarsigner also i can't use Android Studio, i want to do it manually in command prompt.

Comment: @ArnoldParge You are absolutely right! please check my edit.

Comment: @Matiah Thank you. I have posted it as answer. Please tick it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some emulators, release build does not work. Don't worry, go ahead and upload on PlayStore. Btw you can test it on real device though.

**For your new question:**
It should work on on devices with api levels from 16 to 27. Release builds should always be tested on real devices.
Release the app as alpha on PlayStore and ask your people to test it.