# Error while signing an kivy app for the play store

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I made a release apk using **buildozer android release** command. Then I sign and zipalign my apk using following commands.

genarate keystore file [before] - **keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

generate keystore file [after] -  **keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myapp.keystore -destkeystore myapp.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12**

sign apk - **jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myapp.keystore myapp-0.1-arm64-v8a-release-unsigned.apk myalias**

zipalign apk -  **zipalign -v 4 myapp-0.1-arm64-v8a-release-unsigned.apk playstore-release.apk**

After everything done play store gives this error - **You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme**

**target max api 30 and min api 21, sdk 30 used**

How i upload my apk to playstore in 2021

Answer (score 1):

First, your project must be able to run on an android with .apk on debug and unsigned mode.

If it's the case you can read theses 2 steps.

First you must signed your application to be sure that you are the only one that can update it (prevent from malicious algo insertion).

Change this in your `buildozer.spec` file:

#App store ask us to have this architecture and the latest api available (actually 29)

`android.arch = arm64-v8a`

`android.api = 29`

#Each time you update your apk on the app store, you have to incremente this variable by 1. It's 8211 by default BUT BE AWARE, you have to change it from the start (I begin with 1):

`android.numeric_version = 1`

---

Now that your key is signed, go on the terminal and:

---- FULFILL FOLLOWING VARIABLES ----

`project_path=~/MY/PATH`

`key_filename=mykeyfilename`

`key_alias=mykeyaliasname`

`password="turlututu"`

---- TO DO ONLY ONE TIME ----

`mkdir -p ~/keystores/`

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/keystores/$key_filename.keystore -alias $key_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

---- a warning is printed and advice us to migrate to PKCS12 so we do it ----

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ~/keystores/$key_filename.keystore -destkeystore ~/keystores/$key_filename.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12`

---- ENDING OF THE PART TO DO ONLY ONE TIME ----

`export P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE=~/keystores/$key_filename.keystore`
`export P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWD=$password`
`export P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS_PASSWD=$password`
`export P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS=$key_alias`
`cd $project_path`
`buildozer -v android release`

Comment: I personnally let the min/max api variable commented so your error may come from this changement.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will check this

Comment: After done these steps perfectly [max api not changed] play store gives this error -   You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment for the moment so I write here). I don't know for this error and I don't have the time to search sorry.

Little hint: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636725/error-while-trying-to-upload-apk-to-google-play) they talk about **Visual Studio** problem, maybe it's your case ?