# cordova build --> both debug and release builds are working. But when I do `zipalign` it fails to install on my device

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, zipalign

I have created an application using angular and processed it using Cordova.

Now, when I use `cordova build android` or `cordova build --release android` I get the desired result i.e. the app is running on my device, even after signing it (with my.keystore) using the below

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore  name1.apk alias
```

it works fine till here, but when I attempt to zipAlign the same using

```
./zipalign -f -v 4 app-release.apk app-final.apk
```

it shows `Verification successful`, then when I try to install it prompts--> `app not installed` on my device.
What is possibly wrong here?

*Below are the steps in sequence.*

1. put the angular dist build in www folder.
2. generate keystore using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <keystorename> -alias <aliasname> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

3. add keystore && build.json with keystore password.
4. run `cordova build --release android` --> produces app-release.apk
5. then using zipAlign in buildtools

```
./zipalign -f -v 4 app-release.apk app-final.apk
```

Also in `play console` while uploading the generated .apk. I'm getting following:

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?
```

Comment: As Far As I Know, `zipalign` only work from `playstore` you can't install it directly on device.

Comment: Najam, the problem is I'm unable to even upload the ZipAligned apk file. It gives another error in play console.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?

Comment: can you add all steps in your question with exact command you use.

Comment: okay editing my question. Just give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230621/discussion-between-raishav-hanspal-and-najam-us-saqib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have landed here .. my issue was resolved importing the project to Android studio and generating build from there.

check the referenced question --> [Error while trying to upload APK to Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636725/error-while-trying-to-upload-apk-to-google-play)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some steps.
If you are using `build.json`, you have to build APK using this script.

```
cordova build android --release --buildConfig=build.json
```

or after `cordova build android --release`, sign your app using jarsigner.